# Why bash histroy rewrite IP and User data

Tags: linux, bash

I'm use HISTTIMEFORMAT like this:

```
HISTFILESIZE=4000
HISTSIZE=4000
USER_IP="`echo $SSH_CLIENT | awk '{ print $1}'`"
USER_FIO=($USER_RYBAV $USER_TROVL)
HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d/%m/%y %T $USER_IP:$USER_FIO | "
export HISTTIMEFORMAT
```

and in .ssh/authorized_keys

```
environment="USER_TROVL=torvalds.linux" ssh-rsa AAAAB3N....
environment="USER_RYBAV=rybafing.valing" ssh-rsa AAAAB3....
```

And when I'm login by 1 rsa, I got in history:

```
  178  22/07/22 16:48:07 10.100.19.204:torvalds.linux exit
  179  22/07/22 16:48:12 10.100.19.204:torvalds.linux lsblk 
  180  22/07/22 16:48:14 10.100.19.204:torvalds.linux history
```

When I'm loggin by 2 rsa:

```
  178  22/07/22 16:48:07 10.100.19.204:rybafing.valing exit
  179  22/07/22 16:48:12 10.100.19.204:rybafing.valing lsblk 
  180  22/07/22 16:48:14 10.100.19.204:rybafing.valing history
  181  22/07/22 16:48:18 10.100.19.204:rybafing.valing exit
  182  22/07/22 16:48:30 10.100.19.204:rybafing.valing lsblk
```

How you can see $USER_FIO from .bash_profile rewriting at any connection with different keys and env.

I expect no rewrite user logins:

```
  178  22/07/22 16:48:07 10.100.19.204:**torvalds.linux** exit
  179  22/07/22 16:48:12 10.100.19.204:**torvalds.linux** lsblk 
  180  22/07/22 16:48:14 10.100.19.204:**torvalds.linux** history
  181  22/07/22 16:48:18 10.100.19.204:rybafing.valing exit
  182  22/07/22 16:48:30 10.100.19.204:rybafing.valing lsblk
```

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Is the "logging in by 2 rsa" output different from what you expect?  Please describe what you expect the output to look like.

Comment: I dosent whant rewrite username in histrory when make reconnect by differents rsa.

Comment: `USER_FIO` is an array but you only ever look at its first element. Since you use `$USER_RYBAV` and `$USER_TROVL` unquoted in the assignment to the array, the first of these that is non-empty will be the first element of the `USER_FIO` array.  I'm not turning this into an answer, beacause I don't understand the expected logging output.

Comment: Have you looked at the history file itself?  I don't think the contents of `$USER_IP` or `$USER_FIO`  are being written to the file.  The man page only mentions a timestamp is written to the history file when the `HISTTIMEFORMAT` variable is set. I believe the contents of your two variables are being read at the time you invoke the `history` command to view the file's contents, so they reflect the SSH session that's **reading** the history entries, not the sessions that wrote them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be trying to use `.bash_history` as an audit log file.

The `bash` history is not an audit log: it is designed only to help the user to recall & repeat previous commands, not to be used as a reliable record for documenting what has been done, even in a single session.

`bash` will read the history file when the shell session begins. It will keep the history in RAM during the session, and write it back to the file when the session ends. Since you are not setting the `histappend` shell option, the shell will rewrite the entire file, not just add one line per new command. As all the history timestamps are translated from the internal Unix timestamp format to a human-readable date when writing the history file, changing `HISTTIMEFORMAT` will cause the timestamp format to change on all history lines, including those that belong to past sessions. **This is why `bash`'s `HISTTIMEFORMAT` is not suitable for your purpose.**

If you login with a "good" SSH session, then login with a second "evil" session, do things in the "evil" session, then logout first the "evil" session and then the "good" one, the resulting `bash` history file may not show the commands of the "evil" session at all. Depending on shell settings, a command may be omitted from the history file by just prefixing it with a space character. **These are some more reasons why `bash`'s history file is not suitable for use as an audit log.**

Other shells will do this differently, but trying to use the shell history file as an audit log is still a bad idea, as **the user will be able to manipulate the contents of the history file.**

If you need to log who-does-what on a shared account, it will be much more reliable to only allow a restricted set of commands to be used on the shared account via `sudo` or similar. If you must allow the users to run a shell on a shared account, you might need to set up a session recorder. Modern versions of `sudo` can do that: see `log_input` and `log_output` in `man 5 sudoers`, and also `man 8 sudo_logsrvd` for receiving such session records in another host over the network.

If you are trying to do this for the `root` account, then you must assume that the user with root access will be able to manipulate any logs that are stored locally. You will need to set up the logging so that as soon an audit log message is generated, it will be sent to another host (or some other recording mechanism) which is not accessible by the users of the first host.

If you **require** a reliable audit log, you need to do it right. If you don't, a security auditor (or an expert witness in a court of law) will be able to easily disprove the validity of your logs, making them worthless as evidence.